# Creating Wedge Polygon ArcGIS using Python with tangent off one buffered point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, polygon, polygon-creation

I am trying to write a Python code that would create a wedge polygon from two points, with second point buffered to certain distance and then using tangent.

Point A is the origin point, Point B is at a distance from Point A, and is buffered to a certain distance, say 20 feet.  The wedge will be off the tangent on both sides of the buffered Point B, extending to a certain distance.

I have attached a graphic that shows what I am seeking.  The light red area indicates the area I am seeking to create.

[image]

Comment: What do you have so far? Coding questions here are expected to contain a good faith effort. The arcpy documentation has tons of examples.